# Using an NLB for a service as target group in fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I would like to use an NLB and target an ecs fargate service, but i cannot find any option to use ecs service as target group. Is it even possible?

When i create a service in a fargate cluster, i can only use application load balancer as option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of using NLB with ECS for Fargate is explained in AWS Docs for Fargate:

- [Creating a Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-network-load-balancer.html)

Comment: but how can the scale, if you always need to add them manually to your target group?

Comment: @David You don't have to add the manually. You setup auto-scaling for fargate service.

Comment: i see, but i cannot link my NLB to ecs service, how do i do that?

Comment: @David Your question does not provide any information on what you are doing. I gave you direct link to how to setup NLB for Fargate.

Comment: i was using the "new ecs" experience not realizing, that i am missing a lot of options :(, thanks for your help

Comment: @David So is it still unclear how to create the NLB?